Can I use a C++ macro to get a filename out of a variable and create an identifier from it?
I have many C++ (SFML) projects in which I loaded resources through filename paths. Now I'd like to embed those resource files so that I can put standalone executables on GitHub. (I've been running into frustrations trying to use relative paths.) The xxd program will take a resource such as "image1.png" and pretty painlessly transform it into a char array called image1_png. Well and good. But my SFML code is littered with loops that load resources from filenames, á la:
vector<string> textureList = {
   "image1.png",
   "image2.png",
   ...
}

...
for (auto& str : textureList) {
   Texture tx;
   tx.loadFromFile(str);
   textures.push_back(tx);
}

What I'd really like is to use some macro magic in order to accomplish something like this, without having to handwrite a map of the corresponding xxd-generated identifiers for every "textureList" and "soundList" in every project:
for (auto& str : textureList) {
   Texture tx;
   string name = [the part without the extension]
   string ext = [the extension]
   tx.loadFromMemory(XXD_IDENTIFIER(name,ext),XXD_LEN(name,ext));
   textures.push_back(tx);
}

Note that I am not supplying string literals to the macro, I have to work from a loop variable which contains filenames. Is this possible, or do I just have a lot of typing ahead of me?

The build step that creates the symbols and contents can also create the necessary declarations in a header file and then you can include that header file, i.e. no need for manual typing.

@user17732522 I don't think I understand. xxd produces an image1.hpp, image2.hpp, etc. for every "image1.png", "image2.png" resource file. I can include all of those *.hpp's, and within them are the generated symbols image1_png, image1_png_len, etc. They contain all the necessary byte arrays: I've gotten that far.
My question is: can I replace for (auto& fname : rscList) ... texture.loadFromFile(fname) in my existing code with something like texture.loadFromMemory(MACRO(fname), MACRO_LEN(fname)), where the macros somehow

derive the identifiers image1_png and image1_png_len from the argument fname whose actual value is "image1.png". Otherwise I will have to handwrite a map something like "image1.png" -> image1_png, image1_png_len for hundreds of resource files.

No, macros can't do that. But you can for example replace vector<string> by a vector<std::pair<string, unsigned char*>> or whatever and have the build process fill out the initializer of this vector with pairs of file names and names of the byte arrays.

@user17732522 Okay, thanks, I will try to find out how to do that. I assume by "build process" you mean something like CMake? I need to learn how to understand what CMake is doing. Would you by chance be willing to spell out the steps that you mean here in an answer? My question isn't concerned about macros specifically as it is with generating the identifiers without having to handwrite them. Thanks!

Bash script to autogenerate whole headers that contain only these include lists? CMake can generate sources by substitution e.g. with #cmakedefine, but if it's something as simple as globbing a folder and generating a line for every filename, you don't need such smart stuff.

This seems to be a multi-level XY problem. Perhaps you should start with "I've been running into frustrations trying to use relative paths." - You should always use absolute paths. It is not that difficult to obtain absolute path to the folder where executable is located and then form absolute path to some resource files stored along with it (for example by enumerating files in `/exe_folder/textures' subfolder). "I'd like to embed those resource files" - This is also possible, but requires either a resource embedding or an extra linking steps.
